# Can you achieve 100% code coverage for groovy?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, code-coverage, language-comparisons

Groovy being strongly typed dynamic language, is it possible to get 100% code coverage for Groovy?
If not, can we get as close as possible to Java for code coverage?
Are there any better code coverage tools for Groovy than Java?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SonarQube set up properly, it should work about as well as Java. The only real catch I found was that SonarQube seemed to struggle with polyglot projects, but that might not be current as the last version I used was the better part of a year old by now.